# How to completely remove column separators in an html table on Safari? (Border-collapse not fully removing)

Tags: html, css, html-table, safari, mobile-safari

I have an html table, and have applied `border-collapse: collapse`. This is working correctly on Chrome, but on Safari, a small remnant of the cell border seems to be persisting:

[image: image of white line between two green table cells]

It turns out, this is the `<table>` element showing through; when I set `<table>`'s background to red:

[image]

I have looked through dozens of related posts on SO, and all of them boil down to using `border-collapse: collapse` or `border: none`, and none are Safari-specific. Our team has found some partial solutions;

- Setting `border-collapse: collapse` on the cells themselves (`<td>, <th>`), rather than just the `<table>` itself seems to address it on desktop Safari, but not mobile iOS.
- Setting background colors on the `<th>` itself, as well as the `<thead>` above, made the gap much less noticeable.

However, these don't completely address the issue, and both seem hacky. Does anyone know how to *completely* remove this border on Safari?